# AWS EC2 Instance Pointing to Amazon Linux AMI Test Page Rather than WP Site

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I decided to play around with AWS EC2 and set up a Wordpress site on a 64-bit Linux Instance.

I have fully set up the instance with LAMP, installed Wordpress and pointed my domain to the server. When I try to access the site http://latesttech.tips I get the Amazon Linux AMI Test Page and the only way to access Wordpress is to visit http://latesttech.tips/lttwp.

How can I have the primary domain to point to the "lttwp" directory automatically so this doesn't have to be done via the URL?

I'm fairly new in the dev world and looked up how to fix, but couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems to be caused by your Apache configuration. Let's have a look at that. You should paste it in your question. Remember to indent so it is presented as code.

Comment: Thanks @webjay, this is the first time I've used Apache or really done any back-end development. I'll update the post with the Apache config file.

Comment: @Webjay, I was able to get it to point to the correct directory using NMC's answer below, now it looks like PHP isn't working, when I visit http://latesttech.tips only the HTML is showing.

Looks fine on Safari, but not on Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your apache config file to redirect to your lttwp folder.

Usually the configs for apache are in `/etc/httpd/conf` or `/etc/apache2/conf` Look for the directory variable. You will need to edit that path at 2-3 place in the config for it to work. Look for the `documentroot` and `directory` variables.

You can find more info here : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html

Once done, restart the apache server so that it takes new config: `sudo service httpd restart`

Comment: Thanks @NMC! Edited the file and changed the directory path, but now it looks like the theme isn't being registered. If you visit http://latesttech.tips, only the HTML comes up, no PHP.

Comment: I'm not seeing any php outputed in your code, that usually means the code is interpreted like it should. Maybe paste your php code ? or if you did lots of change on your sevrer config, maybe a server restart is the way to go.

Also, make sure that you edit your links to reflect your new address. All your links still redirect to your lttwp folder.

Comment: I just restarted the instance and restarted apache but now it says database connection error. Also how do I change the links? I'm familiar with changing permalinks via Wordpress, but no on the backend. Sorry still learning backend development. Ha ha. Thanks again @NMC.

Comment: This is probably due to wordpress needing the correct credentials and information about your database. I cannot help you there because i don't really use wordpress but you can look under the config file in WP.
As for the links, it also probably means that the wordpress config looks for your old address. I suggest taking the config file of wordpress: `wp-config.php` and check each line to reflect your new config.

Don't forget to vote up my answers and comments if this is helping you.

Comment: And i just thought about something. If you restarted your server. Make sure your database is running `sudo service mysqld start`

Comment: You're the best! Thank you. I'll definitely up-vote when I get 2 more rep. points.

Comment: I restarted the database and that fixed the database error, will check the wp-config file.

Comment: Ended up scrapping that install and started from scratch, got everything up and working. Thanks again @NMC.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to your word press folder is not in APACHE DOCUMENT ROOT..for this you have to move your wp folder to apache document root 
here is the solution that i found http://geekme.me/2015/10/16/how-to-setup-wordpress-blog-on-amazone-ec2-creating-database-tutorial-4/